# how to database using python script

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-connector

I tried to connect to mysql server (database) using following python script but unfortunately got a message in my terminal box in ubuntu 14.04
`ImportError: No module named mysql.connector`

```
enter code here

import mysql.connector

cnx =mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='X',host='127.0.0.1',database='BankMa')

cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you don't have the python connector installed, you can download a .deb package from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)

Comment: no I named my file as connection.py and import another package mysql.connector

Comment: @krishnakumarnokha, you have a mysql.py or mysql.pyc  file somewhere in your path that is not from the mysql package

Comment: no there is no any file named as mysql.py or mysql.pyc in my path file

Comment: @krishnakumarnokha, then you have not installed mysql or you are using the wrong version of python that you installed it for. How did you install it?

Comment: using these three commands sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysql-java

Comment: That has nothing to do with python, where is your python wrapper?

Comment: still i am getting message "ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
"

Comment: then what is problem using this .is it its limitation or somethig else ?

Comment: You can also try `pip install MySQL-python`, you realise mysql and python are completely unrelated? You might also need to install  `libmysqlclient-dev`.

Comment: Did you try installing the .deb? If pip is not installed then did you try installing it?

Comment: i installed  pip and dowloaded mysql-connector-python_2.0.4-1debian7.6_all.deb
  but i don't know how to install it

Comment: `sudo   dkpg -i filename.deb` or simply clicking in the .deb should work

Comment: I just clicked on that .deb file and used it .and run the file to connect to database and it worked .thank you . 
but i have a question what this "pip" does?

Comment: No worries, pip is the de-facto standard package manager for python. Any time you want to install a python package you just pip install package_name